# wp_remote_request not allowed to edit post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have this bizarre problem with sending a PUT request to my `WordPress REST API` with the code below:

```
$id = $post->ID;
    $api = 'http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/' . $id;
$res = wp_remote_request($api,
        ['method' => 'PUT', 
        'headers'  => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic' . base64_encode( 'username:password' )
        ),
        'body' => ['dp_post_attributes' => $att['numPosts']]
        ]);
    var_dump($res);
```

I'm trying to use it to update a REST field title `attributes` and when running this code I get the response below:

> "code":"rest_cannot_edit","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to
>   edit this post."

As far as I know, this is how to authenticate via the `wp_remote_request` function right?

Is there something else I need to be doing? Keep in mind, this is within my own code on the website I am trying to make a request to so I'm not access a website outside of my domain.